# Web API HTTP status codes

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm building a web API and for some situations I'm not sure what status codes to return. Just a note, I'm not trying to create fully compliant REST API, I'm going rather the RPC over HTTP way - if it matters anyhow.

```
-Domain [1]
    - Project [1]
    - Project [2]
    - Project [3]
```

When I'm looking for a project with specific Id and it doesn't exist, I return `404 - Not found`. (`/api/project/show?id=4`)

But when I want to get all projects for a specific domain, which doesn't exist, should I return `400 - Bad request` or `404 - Not found`? (`/api/project/list?domainid=2`)

I'm thinking about making things more simple and consistent and to use just these codes:

- `200 - OK`
- `400 - Bad request` (validation errors, data don't belong to the user, data not found)
- `500 - Internal error` (unhandled exception)

Response with code 400 has special payload describing the error in detail.

Is it a bad idea?

Comment: If the domain (`https://example.com/api/domain`) doesn't exist, why would any request for data within that domain be anything more than a 404? After all the *domain does not exist*.

Comment: My request looks like `/api/project/list?domainid=2`. It's not querying domain, rather projects with some parameters.
If I have request with more parameters '/api/project/list?domainid=2&userid=3` and if anything of the parameters doesn't exist, would it be always 404? It also could be 200 with empty collection, maybe?

Comment: 404 can also have response body. You can include details there. 404 can also mean *something that was necessary was not found*. But if it is a collection which can normally be expected to be empty, a 200 OK with an empty array would probably be best, as the request did finish fine. But if the caller requests a single entity, 404 is very appropriate.